# Compose lazy column not showing updates from Room database

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to read from the Room database as updates are made and render in Compose UI. I am only getting the initial state and updates to the table are not showing up unless I go to the previous screen and come back. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I understand I need to have a ViewModel in between but I suppose the issue will still be there.

UI:

```
@Composable
fun ListScreen(itemKey: String, itemRepository: ItemRepository) {
    val itemList by itemRepository.getItemData(itemKey).collectAsState(initial = listOf())

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 20.dp, horizontal = 10.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        items(itemList) {
            Text(it, style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
fun getItemData(itemKey: String): Flow<List<String>> = dao.getItems(itemKey)
```

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT value FROM ItemEntity WHERE itemKey = :itemKey")
fun getItems(itemKey: String): Flow<List<String>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The code that writes to the database and the one that reads from it were using different RoomDatabase objects. After making sure they are the same, live updates started to show up.